# Data session info on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm building an app and I would like to track my device data session information.

For example duration, received bytes, sent bytes, bearer, access point, local IP address, protocol when connected using wifi, 3g, gprs, cell network.

If I can get all would be perfect, but getting 1 is more than enough.

I hope someone could show me some solutions or possibles APIs, if possible.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 namespaces in WP8 that provide network information:  [System.Net.NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.networkinformation%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), [Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and the new WP8 WinPRT [namespace Windows.Networking.Connectivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.networking.connectivity.aspx).

While [DataUsage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.networking.connectivity.dataplanusage.aspx)/DataPlan APIs are available in the new WP8 namespace, they aren't supported on WP8 and only exist for Win8 API compatibility. You can use either the new WP8 APIs or WP7 APIs to enumerate over all connected interface type and check if they're WiFi/Ethernet/3G/etc:

```cs
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var network in new NetworkInterfaceList())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(network.InterfaceType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't completely understand "While DataUsage/DataPlan APIs are available in the new WP8 namespace, they aren't supported on WP8"

Comment: How is possible to have a namespace for WP8 and aren't supported on WP8?