# How to Get wifi data used by applications in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to get the wifi data used by application in Windows Phone 8.

The use case is as below:

1. Application should run in back ground
2. It should get the total wifi data usage
3. Wifi data used by different applications installed on device

I searched in [NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) but looks like, it does not have the required information

Can any help here?

Regards,

SRS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data season info Windows phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336897/data-season-info-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Windows Phone.